# How to set up Windows Authentication for React + ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, reactjs, windows

I have a client (React) and server side (ASP.NET Core 6). I need to use Windows authentication.

For all guides, I configured the server part, in particular:
`launchSettings.json`:

```
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": true,
  "anonymousAuthentication": false,
  "iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:12640",
  "sslPort": 44317}
}
```

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
    .WithOrigins(configuration.GetSection("CorsOrigins").Get<string[]>())
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()   
    .AllowCredentials();
}));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

appseting.json:

```
"CorsOrigins": [ "http://localhost:3000" ]
```

Controller:

```
[Route("~/api/admin/getUser")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser()
{
    try
    {
        var authData = new IdentityUser()
        {
            Username = User.Identity?.Name,
            IsAuthenticated = User.Identity != null ? User.Identity.IsAuthenticated : false,
            AuthenticationType = User.Identity?.AuthenticationType
        };
        
        return Ok(authData);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"GetAdUser error: {ex}");
        return BadRequest(ex);
    }
}
```

On the front, I have an rtk query with a service to get the user:

```
export const userService = createApi({
  reducerPath: "userService",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: `${config.apiUrl}/api`,
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include",
    headers: new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }),
  }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getUserRoles: build.query<IUserRole, any>({
      query: (userName: string) => `product/getUserRoles?userName=${userName}`,
      transformResponse: (responce: IUserRoleResponse) => {
        return responce.data.getUserRoles;
      },
    }),
    getUser: build.query<IUser, any>({
      query: () => "admin/getUser",
    }),
    getUserAd: build.query<IGetUser, any>({
      query: (userName: string) => `admin/getADUser?userName=${userName}`,
      transformResponse: (responce: IGetAdUsersResponse) => {
        return responce.data.getADUser.user;
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetUserRolesQuery, useGetUserAdQuery, useGetUserQuery } = userService;
```

The problem is `getUser` returns a HTTP 401 error. But if from go to the direct link

```
https://localhost:7054/api/admin/getUser
```

then the answer is successful.

Maybe I have configured something incorrectly?

Headers in browser:

Google Chrome:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 09 Oct 2023 20:50:27 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Vary: Origin
Www-Authenticate: Negotiate
```

Yandex browser

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 09 Oct 2023 20:50:27 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
```

Don't know why but in another browser request return 200.

200 looks like

```
{ 
  "username": "MyUser",
  "isAuthenticated": true,
  "authenticationType": "NTLM"
}
```